# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns' while passing the dataframe name dynamically by user input

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 3 different pandas dataframes given below.
I want to dynamically pass the dataframe name and column name as user input .
Then it should print the column from that dataframe .
Below is my code . And it is throwing the following Error .

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C'], "Age": [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Addr": ['D', 'E', 'F'], "PIN": [4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"State": ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], "Phone": [7, 8, 9]})

def filter_df():
    df_name = input("Enter Datframe")
    column_name = input("Enter Column Name")
    if column_name in df_name.columns:
        print(df_name[column_name])
    else:
        print("Incorrct column Name")

filter_df(df2, 'Addr')
```

Below Error I am Getting after calling the function and giving the inputs:

```
Enter Datframe df1
Enter Column Name Name

Error:
if column_name in df_name.columns:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Please Tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: The input received from the user is a `str`, you need to parse it in some way and convert it to a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that `input()` will become a reference to the `df1`, `df2`, or `df3`. You can fix your problem by calling the `eval()` function on `df_name`. This will open your code up to injection attacks, but I'm assuming that is not an issue for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C'], "Age": [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Addr": ['D', 'E', 'F'], "PIN": [4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"State": ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], "Phone": [7, 8, 9]})

def filter_df():
    df_name = eval(input("Enter Datframe"))
    column_name = input("Enter Column Name")
    if column_name in df_name.columns:
        print(df_name[column_name])
    else:
        print("Incorrct column Name")

filter_df(df2, 'Addr')
```

Comment: `eval` is not safe to use. Instead use `vars()[df_name]`.